# What are the formats to save data to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

After creating a DataFrame I can save it in avro, csv or parquet format.

Is there any other format available in dataframe or rdd by which data can be saved in Hadoop HDFS?

Answer (score 2):

From [What Is Apache Hadoop?](https://hadoop.apache.org/):

> **Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS™)**: A distributed file system that provides high-throughput access to application data.

With that, you can use HDFS to store *virtually* files in any format, including avro, CSV, parquet, etc.

---

In Spark, you specify the format of a DataFrame using [format](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@format(source:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter%5BT%5D) method while the location in a storage using [save](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@save(path:String):Unit) method.

> **format(source: String): DataFrameWriter[T]** Specifies the underlying output data source. Built-in options include "parquet", "json", etc.
>
> **save(path: String): Unit** Saves the content of the DataFrame at the specified path.

You could also use the shortcut to define the format and the path of a DataFrame on a storage using the format-specific methods like `json(path: String)`, `parquet(path: String)` or alike.

Answer (score 0):

- [RDD save*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/search.html?q=rdd%20save&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

  - pyspark.RDD.saveAsHadoopDataset
  - pyspark.RDD.saveAsHadoopFile
  - pyspark.RDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset
  - pyspark.RDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile
  - pyspark.RDD.saveAsPickleFile
  - pyspark.RDD.saveAsSequenceFile pyspark.RDD.saveAsTextFile
- [DataFrame save](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/search.html?q=dataframe%20save)

  - pyspark.sql.DataFrame.save
  - pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save
  - pyspark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsParquetFile
  - pyspark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsTable
  - pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable

Last but not least...

- [Spark Dataframe Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html#generic-loadsave-functions) to better understand how to use the DataFrame Writer.